# OP's comment deleted with no information

Tags: bug, comments

I recently noticed that one of my comments is **missing**.

I am using that term as there is no trace of it anywhere. No moderator message, no action history and no indication of any sort regarding the same.

I would also like to add that the comment was in no way violating the terms of UX StackExchange and was perfectly civilized with no foul language of any sort. Also, it have two upvotes (not that it matters)

I have come across a thread that mentioned that there should be an indication that a comment was deleted as breaks the context. Even if that hasn't been done, the user who **posts the comment** should be aware that his/her comment has been edited/deleted.

Comment: Can you provide a reference to the post where the comment is missing? I noticed that in one of the posts where you have provided an answer and comments to your answer, some minor edits were made that have been approved but I didn't seen any comments deleted. But I can look into this for you. Thanks.

Comment: https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/119196/97993
This is the post I am referring to. I feel like a couple of comments are missing here and I realized that when I read the second comment which feels out of context.

Comment: I have checked the post and found that there is one comment from you that has been deleted. I can understand why you consider the comment being out of context, but in terms of the overall commentary to your answer I don't think the information in the deleted comment is vital to the discussion (as the relevant points have already been made), and therefore no changes are required.